# How to determine the number of redundant address bits?

Tags: avr

A memory module has a data bus that is 128 bits wide. If module holds 4GB (2^31 bytes), how many address bits are redundant?

I believe there is some sort of formula (if not a formula a logical procedure) which we can use to find out the address bus then from there we can find out the redundant number of address bits. I don't have a basic idea of how these things are related: address bus, bus width, data bus.etc.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps _you_ get a more specific and relevant answer!  See also [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and [What makes a good question?](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints)

Answer (score 1):

Each line on one of those parallel buses represents one bit of information. This is why the number of lines that comprise the bus is also referred to its width in *bits*.

The address bus is used to send the *address* to be read from or written to to the memory module. Because each line can 'transport' only one bit multiple lines are used in parallel.

For example, to be able to address 256 different locations in the memory, (at least) 8 lines are required for the address bus (because 2^8 = 256). Those 4 billion memory locations will therefor need 32 bus lines on the address bus, the address bus is 32 bits wide.

Note that I used the word "memory *location*" above, because the address sent to the memory module *may* refer to bytes *or* to some other unit of storage, like "words" (2 bytes) or "double-words" (4 bytes) or something else.

How big the minumum unit of storage that can be directly addressed is depends on the memory module and its internal organisation.

A memory module with a bus width of 128 bits for the data bus can send or receive 128 bits = 16 bytes at the same time. For this kind of memory the smallest addressable unit *may* be 128 bits, so that it could be accessed only in blocks of 16 bytes, which are usually *aligned* on multiples of this block size.

In that case, the first block of 16 bytes would be addressed by address 0 and would occupy the first 16 bytes of memory. Then at address 1 would be the next block, starting at byte #16. Address 2 gives 16 bytes from byte #32, and so on.

So, if each address on the address bus is used to address 16 bytes at the same time, less addresses will be needed to access the whole memory as compared to byte-wise addressing.

To be able to address each *byte* of those 4GB individually, the address bus needs to be 32 bits wide (2^32 bytes= 4GB). If, however, only whole blocks of 16 bytes can be addresses individually, one will only need (2^32)/16 different addressed to address the whole memory. 16 = 2^4, so (2^32)/(2^4) = 2^28. -> 28 bits would be needed to address each whole block of 16 bytes (=128 bits) and the *width* of the address bus could potentially be reduced to 28 lines.